# PKChunking problem when using Content-Type: application/json

Tags: community, batch, json, bulk-api, job

I have the following problem when creating a batch to a job in Salesforce and I want to enable PKChunking.

I perform a POST request at `/services/async/37.0/job` and I am creating the **job** like this:

***Headers***:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer _my_token_
X-SFDC-Session: OAuth _my_token_
Sforce-Enable-PKChunking: true
```

***Content***

```
{
    "operation": "query",
    "ObjectType": "CampaignMember",
    "ContentType": "JSON"
}
```

After that I perform a POST request at `/services/async/37.0/job/{jobId}/batch` and I am creating the **batch** like this:

***Headers***:

```
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer _my_token_
X-SFDC-Session: OAuth _my_token_
Content-Type: application/json
```

***Content***

```
SELECT Id FROM CampaignMember
```

Everything works fine upon this point. When I try to perform a GET request at `/services/async/37.0/job/{jobId}/batch/{batchId}` I get the following:

> InternalServerError : PKChunking failed. InvalidBatch : Wrong content-type for batch (text/csv), job is of type: application/json`

The weird thing is if I change the `Content-Type`, or don't pass it, of the batch POST request I can't create it and I get the following:

> Wrong content-type for batch (text/plain;charset=UTF-8), job is of type: application/json

Can anyone relate to this strange issue?

Comment: Yep, I'm getting the same error.  My guess is that it's related to this known issue:  https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008ZL6AAM